# How to find all authors who have collaborated together in a paper?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

How can I write an SQL query to form a three-column list of author A (author ID), author B (author ID), and the number of collaborated papers between authors A and B. I am using MySQL Server with MYSQL Workbench.

Schema:

```
Authors (
         Author_ID,
         Author_name,
         Paper_ID
);
```

Sample Table Data:

| Author_ID | Author_name | Paper_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jack | 313 |
| 2 | Ray | 313 |
| 2 | Ray | 458 |
| 3 | Amy | 458 |
| 1 | Jack | 458 |
| 2 | Ray | 419 |
| 3 | Amy | 419 |
| 2 | Ray | 619 |
| 3 | Amy | 619 |

Expected Result:

| Author A | Author B | Joint Papers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | Ray | 2 |
| Jack | Amy | 1 |
| Amy | Ray | 3 |

Comment: You have a denormalised design, there should be a separate table of *Authors*, this appears to be a table of *Papers*

Answer (score 0):

Use a self join and aggregation:

```
SELECT a1.Author_name AuthorA, 
       a2.Author_name AuthorB,
       COUNT(*) JointPapers
FROM Authors a1 INNER JOIN Authors a2
ON a1.Paper_ID = a2.Paper_ID AND a1.Author_ID < a2.Author_ID
GROUP BY a1.Author_name, a2.Author_name;
```

Or, if there is a case that 2 authors may have the same name:

```
SELECT a1.Author_ID IDA, a1.Author_name AuthorA, 
       a2.Author_ID IDB, a2.Author_name AuthorB,
       COUNT(*) JointPapers
FROM Authors a1 INNER JOIN Authors a2
ON a1.Paper_ID = a2.Paper_ID AND a1.Author_ID < a2.Author_ID
GROUP BY a1.Author_ID, a1.Author_name, a2.Author_ID, a2.Author_name;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1787e7aefc9c78c862d65ed9cbca50b6).